# EF Core: AddRange(list) runs wrong overload

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext` (for version 1.1.0) has two version of AddRange (and others similar methods):

```
public virtual void AddRange([NotNullAttribute] IEnumerable<object> entities);
public virtual void AddRange([NotNullAttribute] params object[] entities);
```

Second just [casts](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/fd9c545bcf0189cccacd130c7757978996eb0d41/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/DbContext.cs#L853) to `IEnumerable<object>`.

When I write:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Entity> list = ...
context.AddRange(list);
```

second overload runs, and casts array of `object` to `IEnumarable<object>`, where single item is `IReadOnlyCollection<Entity>`. It then pass to `StateManager`.[GetOrCreateEntry](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/24556c26a4bdae6e77e84678b7e0ee5d0e321365/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/StateManager.cs#L125) where it treated as entity itself. I'm not sure this not work really, just found my tests failed because of that piece:

```
dbMock.Setup(x => x.AddRange(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
                .Callback<object[]>(xs =>
                {
                    foreach (var entity in xs) // entity is IReadOnlyCollection<Entity> here
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: When I write the same, my compiler (VS2015) chooses the first (correct) overload.

Comment: I got same result as @IvanStoev when testing out overloads in non-ef environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the list itself to an `IEnumerable<object>`:

```
context.AddRange(list.Cast<object>());
```